# Show that $\partial \sigma (T) \subseteq \sigma_{\text{ap}} (T).$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Show that the boundary of the spectrum is contained in the approximate point spectrum i.e. $$\partial \sigma (T) \subseteq \sigma_{\text{ap}} (T).$$

Let $\lambda \in \partial \sigma (T).$ Then there exists a sequence $\{\mu_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ in $\rho (T)$ (the resolvent of $T$) such that $\mu_n \to \lambda.$ So $T - \mu_n \to T - \lambda.$ Now assuming on the contrary that $\inf\limits_{\|x\|=1} \|(T - \lambda) x\| \gt 0.$ Then I am trying to show that $\lambda \in \rho (T)$ which would lead us to a contradiction. For that we need to show that $\sup\limits_n \left \|(T - \mu_n)^{-1} \right \| \lt \infty.$ By uniform boundedness principle we need only to show that $\sup\limits_n \left \|(T - \mu_n)^{-1}x \right \| \lt \infty$ for all $x \in \mathcal H.$ But I am unable to conclude that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a very well known result in functional analysis which can be found in any standard book e.g. Have a look at proposition $6.7$ (page no. $210$) in the second edition of the book *A Course in Functional Analysis* by John B. Conway which is available online in *PDF* format for free.